# Only root-level navigation destinations are effective for a navigation stack with a homogeneous path

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationstack

I am trying to integrate `NavigationStack` in my SwiftUI app.

I have four views: `CealUIApp`, `OnBoardingView`, `UserTypeView` and `RegisterView`.

I want to navigate from `OnBoardingView` to `UserTypeView` when user presses a button in `OnBoardingView`.

And, navigate from `UserTypeView` to `RegisterView` when user presses a button in `UserTypeView`

Below is my code for CealUIApp

```
@main
struct CealUIApp: App {
    
    @State private var path = [String]()
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            NavigationStack(path: $path){
                OnBoardingView(path: $path)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In `OnBoardingView`

```
Button {
    path.append("UserTypeView")
}
label: {
    Text("Hello")
}
.navigationDestination(for: String.self) { string in
    UserTypeView(path: $path)
}
```

In `UserTypeView`

```
Button {
    path.append("RegisterView")
}
label: {
    Text("Hello")
}
.navigationDestination(for: String.self) { string in
    RegisterView()
}
```

When the button on `UserTypeView` is pressed, it navigates to `UserTypeView` instead of `RegisterView`.

Also, the Xcode logs saying

> Only root-level navigation destinations are effective for a navigation stack with a homogeneous path.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can get rid of `Only root-level navigation destinations are effective for a navigation stack with a homogeneous path` by changing the path type to `NavigationPath`.

```
@State private var path: NavigationPath = .init()
```

But then you get a message/error that I think explains the issue better `A navigationDestination for “Swift.String” was declared earlier on the stack. Only the destination declared closest to the root view of the stack will be used.`

Apple has decided that scanning all views that are available is very inefficient so they will use the `navigationDestination` will take priority.

Just imagine if your `OnBoardingView` also had an option for `"RegisterView"`

```
 .navigationDestination(for: String.self) { string in
        switch string{
        case "UserTypeView":
            UserTypeView(path: $path)
        case "RegisterView":
            Text("fakie register view")
        default:
            Text("No view has been set for \(string)")
        }
        
    }
```

How would SwiftUI pick the right one?

So how to "fix"? You can try this alternative.

```
import SwiftUI

@available(iOS 16.0, *)
struct CealUIApp: View {
    @State private var path: NavigationPath = .init()
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $path){
            OnBoardingView(path: $path)
                .navigationDestination(for: ViewOptions.self) { option in
                    option.view($path)
                }
        }
    }
    //Create an `enum` so you can define your options
    enum ViewOptions{
        case userTypeView
        case register
        //Assign each case with a `View`
        @ViewBuilder func view(_ path: Binding<NavigationPath>) -> some View{
            switch self{
            case .userTypeView:
                UserTypeView(path: path)
            case .register:
                RegisterView()
            }
        }
    }
}
@available(iOS 16.0, *)
struct OnBoardingView: View {
    @Binding var path: NavigationPath
    var body: some View {
        Button {
            //Append to the path the enum value
            path.append(CealUIApp.ViewOptions.userTypeView)
        } label: {
            Text("Hello")
        }
        
    }
}
@available(iOS 16.0, *)
struct UserTypeView: View {
    @Binding var path: NavigationPath
    var body: some View {
        Button {
            //Append to the path the enum value
            path.append(CealUIApp.ViewOptions.register)
        } label: {
            Text("Hello")
        }
        
    }
}
@available(iOS 16.0, *)
struct RegisterView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Register")
        
    }
}
@available(iOS 16.0, *)
struct CealUIApp_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        CealUIApp()
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice explanation for the choice of the Apple (+1). Is there a way to send values to views on this approach other than updating an ObservableObject before the append? I think this approach kills the custom inits of the Views.

Comment: @kelalaka kills the custom init's? You can pass almost anything with the `enum` `Binding` is a limitation but it is a `navigationDestination` limitation not a limitation of this approach.

Comment: Do you mean with the ViewOptions enum? That will complicate the coding. Yes, I'm talking about navigationDestionation. While keeping the same value, we cannot call a different init. I've tried to use different value on another view, and come across this warning. Well, I think the observalble is better solution, and it is core of single-source - model seperated desing, as far as I can see.

Comment: @kelalaka why wouldn’t you be able to a different init? If you are having an issue you can ask a question someone will help you

Comment: while. this approach is clean in routing the views, but it's not the right solution when opening a view such as `RegisterView()` which may take many binding and environment object variables which comes from the previous view 'UserTypeView', how would you pass those variables in a `navigationDestination`  closure that resides in the root view ?

Comment: @JAHelia like I mentioned above Binding is a limitation of NavigationDestinatuon but if you have several properties I would combine them and/or use the version with isPresented

Comment: @loremipsum I want to inject `.environmentObject(someObj)` with a view in the `navigationDestination` closure and this environment object may come from another view, I'm not talking about passing binding specifically.

Comment: @JAHelia you’ll find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75752604/environmentobject-not-injected-for-navigationdestination/75841146#75841146) useful it is a common issue I see freelancing. I don’t recommend using EnvironmentObject if it can’t be injected from the root view. Reference types can be passed around using this method easily.

Comment: I have tried multiple ways of using NavigationStack + NavigationPath but the issue occurs is that I have multiple views and the navigationDestination of current view(the view in which I am appending the path) don't get called but the parent view is getting called. Also, the code is going in infinite loop when we are removing the last element from the path(path.removeLast()). Also, I am getting the above issue "navigationDestination for “Swift.String” ...." when in infinite loop:
I have multiple views from where I need to have .navigationDestination(for:).

Comment: @PratyushPratik sounds like you need to clean up your code. There is no way around the 1 navigationDestination per type.

Comment: @loremipsum I can understand that I need to have only one navigationDestination, but how an I going to send Bindable variable from that particular view to the root view in which navigationDestination is written?

Comment: @PratyushPratik this is all too vague, come up with an MRE and ask a question. Don’t make it vague detail as much as you can why this answer doesn’t resolve the issue.

Answer (score 7):

As an alternative to @lorem ipsum's answer, I'd suggest using `NavigationLink` instead of a `Button` as that will handle adding the values internal `NavigationPath` for `NavigationStack`. I would only add and pass around your own path if you wanted to do navigation programatically (for example after a network request).

First we have an enum to handle the possible routes and creation of their views:

```
enum Route {
    case register
    case userType
    
    @ViewBuilder
    var view: some View {
        switch self {
        case .register:
            RegisterView()
        case .userType:
            UserTypeView()
        }
    }
}
```

Then we have the main app:

```
@main
struct CealUIApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            NavigationStack {
                OnboardingView()
                .navigationDestination(for: Route.self) { route in
                    route.view
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And finally the implementation of those views with the various `NavigationLink` in place:

```
struct OnboardingView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink("Hello", value: Route.userType)
    }
}

struct UserTypeView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink("Hello", value: Route.register)
    }
}

struct RegisterView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Register View")
    }
}
```

Comment: I need to pass a value when the NavigationLink is tapped. How can I do that using this strategy?

Comment: You can add a value to the Route enum, so for example you would have `case userType(String)` so when you have the navigation link it would be `NavigationLink("Hello", value: Route.userType("your value here"))`. And in the view builder in the enum, you can get that value.

Answer (score -1):

Following @lorem ipsum example I think you can change this state variable  `@State private var path: NavigationPath = .init()` with an `@ObservableObject` so you don't need to pass `@Bindings` on all the views. You just pass it down from the `CealUIApp` view as an `WnvironmentObject`

```
class NavigationStack: ObservableObject {
    @Published var paths: NavigationPath = .init()
}


@main
struct CealUIApp: App {
    
    let navstack = NavigationStack()
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
                AppEntry()
                    .environmentObject(navstack)
        }
    }
}

extension CealUIApp {
    enum ScreenDestinations {
        case userTypeView
        case registerView
        
        
        //Assign each case with a `View`
        @ViewBuilder func view(_ path: Binding<NavigationPath>) -> some View {
            switch self{
                case .permissions:
                    UserTypeView()
                case .seedPhrase:
                    RegisterView()
            }
        }
    }

}


// An extra view after the AppView

struct AppEntry: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var navStack: NavigationStack
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $navStack.paths) {
            OnBoardingView()
                .navigationDestination(for: CealUIApp.ScreenDestinations.self) {
                    $0.view($navStack.paths)
                }
        }
    }
}
```

And then the rest remain the same as @lorem ipsum said.

Comment: `NavigationStack`, which you are redefining, already exists in SwiftUI.

Comment: Not caring about the basics of software engineering isn't smart.