# How do I get rid of "A navigationDestination for AppExample.ViewOptions was declared earlier on the stack. Only the destination declared closest .."

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, navigation, swiftui-navigationstack

I have implemented a navigation stack and enum following https://stackoverflow.com/a/74362840/21094465 yet I am still receiving the following "A navigationDestination for AppExample.GreaterViewOptions was declared earlier on the stack. Only the destination declared closest to the root view of the stack will be used" when I navigate past the second view.

My enum

```
enum GreaterViewOptions {
    case whatIsNewView
    case contentView
    case setUpStart
    case setUpStepOne
    case setUpStepTwo
    case connectionSuccessful
    case firmwareUpdateView
    case registerView
    @ViewBuilder func view(_ path: Binding<NavigationPath>) -> some View{
               switch self{
               case .whatIsNewView:
                   WelcomeScreenView(path: path)
               case .contentView:
                   ContentView(path: path).environmentObject(SheetManager())
               case .setUpStart:
                   SetupGuideSearchView(path: path)
               case .setUpStepOne:
                   SetupGuideConnectionStepOneView(path: path)
               case .setUpStepTwo:
                   SetupGuideConnectionStepTwoView(path: path)
               case .connectionSuccessful:
                   ConnectionSuccessfulView(path: path)
               case .firmwareUpdateView:
                   FirmwareUpdateView(path: path)
               case .registerView:
                   RegisterView(path: path)
               }
           }
}
```

and like I saw, I'm calling it by appending to the path as follows:

```
  Button(action: {
            path.append(GreaterViewOptions.whatIsNewView)
        }) {
            Text("CONTINUE")
                .foregroundColor(.white)
        }
```

and so my sequence of views goes as follows (just the first couple)

Initial View

```
struct BumperScreen: View {
    
    init(viewModel: @autoclosure @escaping () -> BumperScreenViewModel) {
        self._viewModel = .init(wrappedValue: viewModel())
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $path) {
                ZStack {
                    Color(.trulliGold)
                        .ignoresSafeArea()
                    VStack {
                        if show {
                            Spacer()
                            loadAnimation
                                .frame(width: 150, height: 150)
                                .task {
                                    try? await viewModel.getDataFromAPI()
                                    try? await Task.sleep(for: Duration.seconds(1))
                                    doneLoading.toggle()
                                    show.toggle()
                                    path.append(GreaterViewOptions.contentView)
                                }
                            Spacer()
                            
                        } else {
                            launchAnimation
                        }
                    }
                }
                .navigationDestination(for: GreaterViewOptions.self) { option in
                    option.view($path)
                }
        }
    }
```

which brings us to our list of policies that you have to check:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var sheetManager: SheetManager
    
    var body: some View {

            ZStack {
                Color(.trulliGold)
                    .ignoresSafeArea()
                VStack {

                    Spacer()
                    headerStatement
                    Spacer()
                    VStack {
                        privacyPolicy
                        bluetoothPolicy
                        locationsPolicy
                        notificationsPolicy
                        apprunningPolicy
                    }
                    Spacer()
                    Spacer()
                    continueButton
                }
            }
            .popup(with: sheetManager)
        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden()
    }
}

var continueButton: some View {
        Button(action: {
            path.append(GreaterViewOptions.whatIsNewView)
        }) {
            Text("CONTINUE")
                .foregroundColor(.white)
        }
        .disabled(!self.areAllChecked)
        .padding()
        .background(Color.orange)
        .foregroundColor(.white)
        .clipShape(Capsule())
        .padding(.bottom, 32)
    }
```

There's no warning from the BumperScreen to ContentView, but there is the warning I said earlier from ContentView to the third view and views thereafter.

```
struct WelcomeScreenView: View {    
    var body: some View {
            ZStack {
                Color(.gold)
                    .ignoresSafeArea()
                VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 8) {
                    
                    header
                    Spacer()
                    tabView
                    Spacer()
                    Spacer()
                    nextButton
                    closeButton
                }
            }
        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
    }
}
```

I've tried adding the navigationDestination modifier to the Content and Welcome views but the app keeps being sent back to the BumperScreen, leading me to believe that way is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `enum`, `@ViewBuilder` and view model. Use a `navigationDestination` per model value. Don't try to put view structs in the navigation path.

Comment: I'm not sure if I quite understand what you're suggesting. Could you be more specific or offer some pieces of code showing what you mean?