# A navigationDestination was declared earlier on the stack

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationstack

how to fix this error on the console:

> A navigationDestination for “Cost_Control.Movement” was declared earlier on the stack. Only the destination declared closest to the root view of the stack will be used

On my Expenses View I want the user to be able to navigate to AddMovments view by tapping on the toolbar button and when user tap on one of the row of my List be able to navigate to the details.

The app works correctly but I don't understand why the above message is in console:
How to fix it.

```
struct Expenses: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
    var dm : DataManager
    @Query(animation: .snappy) var movments : [Movement]
    @State var addMovments = false
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack{
            
            List{
                
                ForEach(filter(array: movments),id:\.0){ dt in
                    Section("\(dt.0)", isExpanded: .constant(true)) {
                        ForEach(dt.1) { item in
                            NavigationLink(value: item) {
                                HStack{
                                    VStack(alignment:.leading){
                                        Text(item.title)
                                    }
                                    .lineLimit(1)
                                    Spacer(minLength: 5)
                                    Text(item.ammountString)
                                        .font(.title3.bold())
                                }
                            }
                            .navigationDestination(for: Movement.self) { mov in
                                Text("Details of \(mov.title) - \(mov.ammount)")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                
            }
            
            
            .navigationTitle("Movements")
            .toolbar(content: {
                Button(action: {
                    addMovments.toggle()
                }, label: {
                    Image(systemName: "plus.circle.fill")
                        .font(.title3)
                })
                //This looks the issue ---------------------
                .navigationDestination(isPresented: $addMovments, destination: {
                    AddMovments(dm:dm, addMovments: $addMovments)
                })
            })
        }
    }
    func filter(array: [Movement])->[(String, [Movement])] {
        let dict = Dictionary(grouping: array, by: { $0.dateString })
        let sort = dict.sorted(by: { $0.key < $1.key })
        return sort
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Only root-level navigation destinations are effective for a navigation stack with a homogeneous path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74362455/only-root-level-navigation-destinations-are-effective-for-a-navigation-stack-wit)

Comment: Have you tried applying .navigationDestination to the List itself rather than the links.