# SwiftUI NavigationStack: Destination does not show up but shows same view again

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationstack

In the following sample app, why after tapping on "Second Destination" does the same screen show up again instead of actually showing the `SecondDestination`?

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            NavigationLink { 
                FirstDestination()
            } label: { 
                Text("First Destination")
            }

        }
    }
}

struct FirstDestination: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink("Second Destination", value: "my name").navigationDestination(for: String.self) { name in
            SecondDestination(name: name)
        }
    }
}

struct SecondDestination: View {
    
    let name: String
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(name)
    }
}
```

Comment: Running your code, I get a warning: "A navigationDestination for “Swift.String” was declared earlier on the stack. Only the destination declared closest to the root view of the stack will be used."
So this is the same as problem explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74362455/only-root-level-navigation-destinations-are-effective-for-a-navigation-stack-wit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are mixing two different approaches two navigation, the "old" one with `NavigationLink(destination:)` and the "new" one `NavigationLink(value:)`.

Mixing both approaches *does not work*. You will have to decide to either only use the links where you directly define the destination or the one where you define a value and then later on define a `.navigationDestination(for:)` for the value.

**Explanation:**

To understand why you can't mix those approaches, it helps to look at `NavigationStack` and what it can do when you provide a `path` as an input like this: `NavigationStack(path: $path)`. [Even if you don't define it explicitly, SwiftUI will do it internally.]

`path` is a collection of values that represent your navigation path. It contains all the `values` that you pushed onto the stack via `NavigationLink(value:)`. Each of the values in that `path` represents one view, one level of navigation in your `NavigationStack` and you can interact with the navigation in code by adding or removing elements to/from the `path` and the UI will adapt accordingly.

However, if you then also use `NavigationLink(destination:)` somewhere, what would be the `value` that gets added to the `path` when the user taps on that link? The answer is: **none**. *There is no value*. That `NavigationLink` only defines a destination view. So SwiftUI tries to do its best to show the destination view, but then can't append something to the `path`.

So if you then try to remove the last element from the `path`, you will not remove the "last view on the stack", but the second to last. Similarly, if you try to append something to the `path`, SwiftUI can't really put it above the currently presented view, because that view simply does not exist within `path`. The result is that the newly added view is shown, but "beneath" the view you navigated to via `NavigationLink(destination:)`.

I hope this helps you understand why you can't mix the two approaches.
Decide on one and things will work.